# Why a "Lost Paradise" in code, that ran many months in py2.7, now np.ndarray() not found in namespaces, while [import numpy as np] was executed?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, anaconda, python-import, namespace-organisation

My question is: was there any namespace handling change between 2.7.9 and 2.7.11?

(I strived to narrow/isolate the issue, but for below-mentioned reasons, it is practically impossible to post an MCVE).

Below posted in-vivo diagnostics has proved, there are no namespace-issues with np.ndarray calls until the very first line trying to access / use numpy ( np ) symbol a line 14644 (14630 in the original numbering)

```
  aDSegFLOAT = np.ndarray( ( 80, 7 ), ...
```

where a thereto working numpy call suddenly raises an exception:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'np' referenced before assignment

---

**Intro:**
For the purpose of a quantitative modelling, a rather extensive `python` module code is being re-used in a distributed processing framework operated for technical analyses and predictions. Due to a fact, that quant-models ( being used for predictions ) are generated at a remarkable cost of small tens-of-CPU-core-hours, there were deployed some additional measures allowing a stateful module `reload( QuantFX )`-s, so that these protect the already elaborated instances of the quant-models, but allow for module functionalities to be updated, tweaked and re-tested on-the-fly.

**Facts:**
`import QuantFX` ceased to work and throws exceptions on `numpy` calls, that were not modified:

- module code was used about a last 12 months, updating just [QUANT-TOOLS],[MODEL] sections
- the code is a Python 2.7 part of a multi-party distributed processing, so an attempt for a MCVE will never reflect / replicate the ecosystem behaviour

**When the problem started:**
After loading a recent Anaconda ( `miniconda` 4.0.0 / 4.0.5 ) package manager for a `VM02/wXP` host, also `python` got re-dressed into 2.7.11 and a module called `QuantFX.py`, being until this update run without any problems in other Anaconda 2.2.0 (32-bit) installations in python `2.7.9` stopped working with a strange looking exception

**What demonstrates an ill-functioning state-of-operations:**
The very `import QuantFX` goes well as it does for dozen months, week by week. A call to `QuantFX.aMiniRESPONDER()` now results in an exception / yields a `Traceback` as if the `numpy` were not `import`-ed at all ( ref. Line 221 ) **but assumed to be some local variable**.

```
    ... 
    [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:<infrastructure-setup>
    START:
           Sun Apr 17 20:19:33 2016 ...
    [aMiniRESPONDER]: final attempt to de-block a remote-processing failed at aXmitSOCKET.send()
    
    SIG->: Sun Apr 17 20:19:33 2016 PUB-lished a <_|SIG_EXIT|_> signal to peers, will sleep( 3 ) to allow for reception
    ZMQ:
           Sun Apr 17 20:19:36 2016 Graceful Exit Done. RET(0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "QuantFX.py", line 14630, in aMiniRESPONDER
        aDSegFLOAT= np.ndarray( ( 80, 7 ),
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'np' referenced before assignment
```

( while a manual call to the very same `numpy` function on interpreter command line prompt,
respecting the `namespace` into which the `numpy` was `import`-ed by the module ( Line 221 below ) 
went well

```
|>>> QuantFX.np.ndarray( ( 2, 3 ), dtype = QuantFX.np.float32, order = 'F' )
array([[  1.22325565e+10,  -2.81789980e-05,   1.22325565e+10],
       [  1.91215026e+00,  -1.81719875e+00,   1.91215026e+00]], dtype=float32)
+0:00:13.282000
22:20:54
|
|>>> QuantFX.np.__version__
'1.10.4'
+0:00:24.438000
22:21:18
|
```

).

### Line 14630 context of the `Traceback` and details:

[image: local-view-on-Traceback + Context-less modus operandi late-imports, incl. numpy Line 14426]

### Line 221 `import numpy as np` + the concept for State-Full reloads:

[image: ![global-view-on-module + import numpy as np # Line 221]

While `QuantFX` module coding might attract objections with regard to PEP* et al, the syntax-constructors were decided so as to allow both a context-full modus operandi via `import`/`reload()` and also fast and safe context-less light-weight operations in minimalistic RAM/CPU consuming remote terminals via select/copy/paste just a single component-code for a diagnostic or a control-CLI purposes ( like a `aRemoteKEYBOARD()` or `aMiniRESPONDER()` ) but without a need to `import` the whole `QuantFX` module ( provisioning late-imports, including the said `numpy` ( Line 14426 ) for such `QuantFX`-Context-less modus operandi ).

---

### **What is sought:**

Any explanations about changes between 2.7.9 and 2.7.11, that could be related to the observed `np.ndarray()` collisions, introduced just last Friday.

Any recommendations for an alternative module syntax-constructors' layout is also of a high value if such proposal preserves both the statefulness during `reload( QuantFX )` and permits both a context-full and a context-less code-base component usage.

---

### Update:

in contrast to its possible appearance, this post was preceded with due review and debugging efforts for adding in-vivo self-diagnostics so as to allow for a problem isolation

```
   """ DEBUG: VM02, after about-a-year working here stable... THROWS EXC. HERE: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'np' referenced before assignment"                                 ????? .EXC on np.ndarray()
            >>> import QuantFX
            Is QuantFX_FLAG seen in dir() during <module> import:  True
            SECTION: ____IDENTIFY____ [TRY].OK
            SECTION: ____IDENTIFY____ [FIN]
            SECTION: import           [TRY].OK
            SECTION: import           [FIN]
            SECTION: FX-MARKET CONTEXTs [TRY].OK
            SECTION: FX-MARKET CONTEXTs [FIN]
            SECTION:    GENERAL TOOLS [TRY].OK
            SECTION:    GENERAL TOOLS [FIN]
            SECTION:     DATA INPUTs [TRY].OK
            SECTION:     DATA INPUTs [FIN]
            SECTION: v41 PROCESS [TRY].OK
            SECTION: v41 PROCESS [FIN]
            SECTION: v41 QUANT TOOLS [TRY].OK
            SECTION: v41 QUANT TOOLS [FIN]
            QuantFX.py:10966: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
            ST2  = np.where( ST2 != 0, ( ST[-LLV.shape[0]:] - LLV ) /  ST2, ST2 ) # / ST2 ( == HHV - LLV )          #        __main__:4162: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
            SECTION: v41 MODEL [TRY].OK
            SECTION: v41 MODEL [FIN]
            SECTION: v41 PREDICTOR [TRY].OK
            SECTION: v41 PREDICTOR [FIN]
            SECTION: MetaTrader RESPONDER [TRY].OK
            SECTION: MetaTrader RESPONDER [FIN]
            SECTION: ____TEMPLATE____ [TRY].OK
            SECTION: ____TEMPLATE____ [FIN]
            SECTION: ____TEMPLATE____ [TRY].OK
            SECTION: ____TEMPLATE____ [FIN]
            SECTION: ____TEMPLATE____ [TRY].OK
            SECTION: ____TEMPLATE____ [FIN]
            +0:00:01.219000
            18:20:14
            |
            |>>> QuantFX.aMiniRESPONDER( aTarget2Bind2_URL = "tcp://10.0.0.62:9999", anInstrumentDictOfPARAMs = QuantFX.anFxCTX[ QuantFX.aCtxID ] )
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: runs in it's own full QuantFX context
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: imports DONE
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: variables DONE
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:[aZmqCONTEXT] <class 'zmq.sugar.context.Context'> setup with 15.2.0 version
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets     [aXmitSOCKET]-pre
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets     (aXmitSOCKET)-to be instantiated-via a call to aZmqCONTEXT.socket( zmq.PAIR )
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets     [aXmitSOCKET]-post
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets     [aXmitSOCKET]-bind()
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:[aXmitSOCKET]
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:[aCtrlSOCKET]
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:[aSIGsSOCKET]
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:<infrastructure-setup>
            START:
                Sun Apr 17 20:19:33 2016 ...
            [aMiniRESPONDER]: final attempt to de-block a remote-processing failed at aXmitSOCKET.send()
            
            SIG->: Sun Apr 17 20:19:33 2016 PUB-lished a <_|SIG_EXIT|_> signal to peers, will sleep( 3 ) to allow for reception
            ZMQ:
                Sun Apr 17 20:19:36 2016 Graceful Exit Done. RET(0)
            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
            File "QuantFX.py", line 14630, in aMiniRESPONDER
                aDSegFLOAT= np.ndarray( ( 80, 7 ),                    
            UnboundLocalError: local variable 'np' referenced before assignment
```

### In-vivo numpy-nd.array-symbol-checker

With an in-vivo checker idea proposal from [@viraptor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31667/viraptor)

```
    def debug_check_np_ndarray( aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO ):      # DEBUG-CHECK
        #ebug_check_np_ndarray( aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO = getframeinfo( currentframe() ) )
        #rom inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo              # EXTERNAL RESPONSIBILITY TO import + setup aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO .OnCall
        
        #ef         np_check():                                     # DEF:

        try:                                                        # TRY: np.*
            np.ndarray
            print 70*" ", "* NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE: ", aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO.filename, " LINE: ", aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO.lineno
            
        except:                                                     # EXC: found the issue
            print 70*" ", "* NP: np.ndarray call [**], FILE: ", aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO.filename, " LINE: ", aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO.lineno
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()             # prepare a traceback detail
            traceback.print_tb(  exc_traceback, limit = 5, file = sys.stdout )
            raise
            
        else:                                                       # ELSE: ok, passed
            #rint("* NP check ok")  # optionally add current function name via a traceback module
            return
```

On launch provides a detailed line-by-line confirmation there was no np.ndarray symbol-masking **until the `Line 14644`** crashes on **`aDSegFLOAT = np.ndarray( ... )`**:

```
|>>> QuantFX.aMiniRESPONDER()
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14387
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14391
[aMiniRESPONDER]: runs in it's own full QuantFX context
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14395
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14404
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14410
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14412
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14419
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14423
[aMiniRESPONDER]: runs in a full QuantFX mode, few imports DONE
[aMiniRESPONDER]: imports DONE
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14441
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14443
[aMiniRESPONDER]: variables DONE
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14454
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14527
[aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:[aZmqCONTEXT] <class 'zmq.sugar.context.Context'> setup with 15.2.0 version
[aMiniRESPONDER]: messaging & signalling sockets RTO:<infrastructure-setup>
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14626
START:
    Tue Apr 19 16:02:12 2016 ...
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14632
                                                                    * NP: np.ndarray call [OK], FILE:  QuantFX.py  LINE:  14643

[aMiniRESPONDER].FINALLY: will start attempts to de-block a remote-processing ( after a prior intentional SIG_EXIT or an unhandled EXC )
[aMiniRESPONDER]: final attempt to de-block a remote-processing failed at aXmitSOCKET.send()
[aMiniRESPONDER]: final attempt to propagate a signal to peers failed at aSIGsSOCKET.send()

EXC. ZmqError(ZMQError('No such file or directory')) on aSIGsSOCKET .setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 ) / .close( aSIGsSOCKET )
EXC. ZmqError(ZMQError('No such file or directory')) on aCtrlSOCKET .setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 ) / .close( aCtrlSOCKET )
EXC. ZmqError(ZMQError('No such file or directory')) on aXmitSOCKET .setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 ) / .close( aXmitSOCKET )

ZMQ:
    Tue Apr 19 16:02:15 2016 Graceful Exit Done. RET(0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "QuantFX.py", line 14644, in aMiniRESPONDER
    aDSegFLOAT          = np.ndarray( ( 80, 7 ),                    #           #  DSegFLOAT[][]                                  ### ToDo.MS: size-independent ( 80+ )                   np.*()  :::::::::::::::
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'np' referenced before assignment
+0:00:10.734000
16:02:15
|
```

Answer (score 6):

From the code you're showing, it's unlikely/impossible that the python update changed anything in the screenshoted code.

What could change is either the environment, or code in other places that was supposed to not set `aMiniRESPONDER_in_full_QuantFX_CONTEXT`. In case that variable is set, the `import numpy as np` is commented and you'd get the exception you're showing here.

Some debugging ideas: either run in a debugger, or use `print`-debug and break/print in places where you think numpy should be imported - likely you'll find that you're just not going into those branches.

Another one: Change one thing at a time. If I understand the question correctly, you changed: python, package manager and deployment environment all in one go and discovered that stuff doesn't work anymore in a way you don't understand. Go back to the original environment and retest. Then upgrade python and nothing else. Retest. Then upgrade package manager (but not packages!). Retest. ... Until you find exactly which change breaks your app.

Another one: When something fails and you can't recover from it (for example failed import), don't continue. On the second screenshot you've got a lot of `import` statements in a `try` block, which will simply ignore the errors and continue execution. (L 328-332). If you continue, something will just explode later on. If the rest of the code looks like that - yes, you'll end up with silent failures and no idea where they come from.

Another one to check @hpaulj's suggestion. Very crude approach: create a function like:

```
def np_check():
    try:
        np.ndarray
    except:
        # found the issue
        raise
    else:
        print("* NP check ok")  # optionally add current function name via traceback module
```

Sprinkle that around the code to find out where's the first place when the `np` name "disappears". Put the first call right after the `import` you expect to work, so that you see at least one "* NP check ok" before the error. Then you just need to add more checks between the place of last success and the first failure, until you isolate the line which causes issues.

Comment: Thanks for a lightning-fast response. You might have noticed, that having launched the module by an **`import QuantFX`**, the Line 221 imports `numpy` unconditionally ( a `def aMiniRESPONDER(...):` *internal* late `import` is setup for a context-less modus operandi, if just this code-snippet is being run, in which case it also import-s `numpy` via the Line 14426 ), so no missed import(s) are possible.

Comment: I'd still go through the steps of upgrading one thing at a time to find what really caused the change, but @hpaulj 's answer may lead to a solution too. And a bit offtopic - if you're in a functioning automatic trading company you could really hire a few serious python programmers to clean this up... The screenshots are honestly scary.

Comment: Confirming the rollback and step-wise rolling forward, so as to isolate the environment change. An unfortunate assignment, demonstrated by @hpaulj, that would introduce a namespace masking ( either for an "np" or an "np.ndarray" symbol ) was lexically cross-checked as negative ( principle is clear, however the module source-code does not contain any such symbol assignment ).

Comment: @user3666197 Added another idea to double-check what hpaulj's suggesting. You can get rid of that name in a few ways - I wouldn't rely on scanning the sourcecode only in this case.

Comment: Yes, a much better way to validate through the namespace services in-vivo, than a regex on source.

Comment: an attempt to `np_check()` the code just underlines the isolated issue on `Traceback` -ed Line 14644: `aDSegFLOAT = np.ndarray(...)` **repeating the statement `... local variable 'np' referenced before assignment`**

Comment: @user3666197 So you're saying if you put `np_check()` right before that line, it passes? If it doesn't you can narrow it down a bit more.

Comment: Right, having added upon your proposal a call to **`debug_check_np_ndarray( aCallerSideInspectFrameINFO = getframeinfo( currentframe() ) )`** right to the line before **`Line 14643:`**, which reports **`numpy`** ( as `np` ) to be processed `[OK]` in the appended journal, the very next line **`Line 14644:`** `aDSegFLOAT = np.ndarray(...)` throws exception as commented right before your comment above. *( journal reports lines from **`finally:`** part of the code too, where ZMQ errors are not relevant ( we test the issue without the full distributed infrastructure ), but the Traceback is clear )*

Comment: Interesting. So it looks like `np` only disappears in that scope, not in the check one. I wonder what would happen if you replace all the debug check calls with just: `np.ndarray`. It will be free of side-effects, but it will actually validate the scope we're interested in and not one in the function call. (basically `np` cannot cannot disappear between your check call and the next line, something much more fun is going on here)

Comment: Yes, it is interesting & serious incident, otherwise I would not bother asking, nevertheless I would dare call it a fun. If it were not blocking the QuantFX code-base usage a week already, it might be an interesting bug-tracking. Not in this state. **The replacements** of a self-diagnosing `debug_check_np_ndarray()` **with direct `np.ndarray()` calls fail to exception on the very first such line.** Indeed a big trouble with namespace-handling.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce your error with a simple script - I import a module and use it once fine.  But the 2nd time I use it, the global assignment gets masked by a local one.  This masking occurs even though the local assignment occurs after the attempted use.

```
import collections    
def foo1():
   dd=collections.defaultdict(list)
   return dd

def foo2():
   dd=collections.defaultdict(int)
   collections = []
   return dd

print foo1()
print foo2()
```

produces

```
2112:~/mypy$ python stack1.py
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack1.py", line 13, in <module>
    print foo2()
  File "stack1.py", line 8, in foo2
    dd=collections.defaultdict(int)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'collections' referenced before assignment
```

Search your code, or possibly something that you call, for a `np=...` like statement.  For a start look at `QuantFX.aMiniRESPONDER`, since that is the immediate context of the error.

Changing my test function to

```
def foo2():
   dd = foo1()
   collections = []
   return dd
```

does not produce the error.  So the masking has a rather limited scope.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj. Attempts to find any such assignment, that would mask **`np`** symbol turned out negative.

Comment: The same confirmed by an in-vivo diagnostics, which has proved, there are no namespace-issues with **np.ndarray** calls until the very line 14644 (14630 in the orignal numbering ) 
          aDSegFLOAT = np.ndarray( ( 80, 7 ), ...

          where an upto thereto working numpy call suddenly raises an exception:

          UnboundLocalError: local variable 'np' referenced before assignment